# Laravel Validating Radio button input

Tags: php, laravel

I have five radio buttons with the values

```
value="1"
value="2"
value="3"
value="4"
value="5"
```

Obviously I only receive one value.

How can I use the Laravel validator

```
$this->validate($request, [
```

To make sure the input is either 1,2,3,4 or 5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `in` validation rule:

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'field_name' => 'in:1,2,3,4,5'
]);
```

You can read more about this in the [Laravel Validation Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-in).

Comment: Laravel is awesome, I can't believe i've just found out about it, could of saved me so much time I feel like punching my self.